# Link to league table in Area 51 Discussion Zone leads to 404 error

Tags: bug, area-51, reputation-leagues, 404-not-found

> [image]

The "top 10% overall" link goes to this URL:

https://stackexchange.com/leagues/194/alltime/area51-meta/0001-01-01/112562#112562

which is a 404 error.

Comment: assuming that 0001-01-01 should be a date we went back in time ... a lot ...

Comment: @rene even the URL https://stackexchange.com/leagues/194 is a 404 error, so the link shouldn't be there. The league tables for Area 51 simply don't exist.

Comment: Happens only in the "meta" site of Area51, which simply use the new-ish profile page design.